# PHP Текст в 1 строку

Tags: php

Всем привет, народ есть код:

```
echo '<h2 class="hyphenate text" lang="ru"> '.JText::_(' Параметры объявления'). JHTML::_('content.prepare',$item->description).'</h2>';
```

Суть в том что строчка "Параметры объявления" выполняется с новой строки а хотелось бы объединить все в 1 строчку - подскажите пожалуйста как построить  код таким образом что бы все было в 1 строчку. Спасибо.

Comment: а что это за странный символ перед строкой "Параметры обновления"?

Comment: Шрифт фонт авесоме - он просто не воспроизводится в php но на сайте все нормально выглядит. @Skywave так вы можете мне помочь или нет?

Comment: перевод строки может быть из за ряда причин: ширина контейнера, css стили, символы/теги перевода строки и тд. Плюс неизвестно что такое JText, JHtml. Поэтому сказать точно не могу. Напишите что на выходе этого скрипта получается. Какой html?

Comment: <div class="desc_content" itemprop="description"><h2 class="hyphenate text" lang="ru"> <p>текст </p>
</h2></div> @Skywave как я понял суть нужно текст вынуть из тега <p> что бы он вписывался в H2

Comment: видимо JText оборачивает текст в <p/>. Попробуйте его не использовать